# Jboss 6 with Java 7 Watcher

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

We need to know the best practice in this case..

We need to watch a XML file in the NAS from our web app on Jboss 6, in the case.. if this xml has changes execute or trigger a Backend process.

My question here is about the best practice to do that..?

a) Native Jboss Class

b) Create a Sevlet

Comment: **What** is a "Native Jboss Class"?

Comment: I found this: org.jboss.varia.scheduler.ScheduleManager, the idea it's start the task without limit, and use the whatcher to control the changes in the file system, but I'm not sure if there is another better option..